# Enable editing of only one feature in Polygon Layer using PyQGIS?

Tags: polygon, pyqgis, editing

I was thinking of locking neighboring polygons (parcels) by disabling editing on them, while editing would be possible on the polygon at the center. This means other polygons can also be edited in case when the coordinate or border of that editable polygon moves.

Is that possible to do in PyQGIS?

I want this to lock editing on the other features.